# Iterate through array of objects of array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can i iterate through a structure like this in JS , basically it's an array containg an array of objects
This is what I get when I console.log it

```
[Array(1)]
0: Array(1)
0: {day: "Friday", start: "2:00", end: "7:30"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I have tried this

```
formattedShifts.map(shift => shift.end)
```

But it fails, formattedShifts it's the array i push into
this is where I create the array

```
  let formattedShifts = [];
    if(props.formData.isLinkedShifts) {
      //converts shift.startTime and shift.endTime format 
      function toDays(startDateString, endDateString) {
        const formatString = 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ';
        const startDate = moment(startDateString, formatString);
        const endDate = moment(endDateString, formatString);
        const start = startDate.format('H:mm');
        const end = endDate.format('H:mm');

        const dates = [];

        while(startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate, 'day')) {
          let currentDay = startDate.format('dddd');
          dates.push({day: currentDay, start: start, end: end});
          startDate.add(1, 'days');
        }
        return dates;
      }
      formattedShifts.push( toDays( props.formData.shifts.map( shift => shift.startTime), 
        props.formData.shifts.map( shift => shift.endTime)) );

    }
```

Comment: don't add the console log of your array. Please add the actual array

Comment: Check edits, should be good

Answer (score 0):

As per your console result, I assuming that your array is something like

```
Var a = [
  {
    day: "Friday", 
    start: "2:00", 
    end: "7:30"
  }
]
```

So you can traverse through this like,

```
a.forEach(function(item) {console.log(item)})   //{day: "Friday", start: "2:00", end: "7:30"}

a.forEach(function(item) {
  for (i in item) { 
     console.log(i, item[i])
  }
})
```

Console result will be like

```
day Friday // i will give the key (day), item[i] will give the value of key (Friday)
start 2:00
end 7:30
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you have added the Array in the question like this:

You need to iterate it:

```js
var a = [[{day: "Friday", start: "2:00", end: "7:30"}, {day: "Friday", start: "2:00", end: "12:30"},{day: "Friday", start: "2:00", end: "8:30"} ,{day: "Friday", start: "2:00", end: "09:30"}]]

const ends = a[0].map(value => value.end);

console.log(ends)
```

You need to iterate over the first element of your `array of array of object`